# EF6 DataAnnotations on Entity, EntityDto or both?

Tags: entity-framework

I have Entity class fields decorated with annotations such as [Required, [DisplayFormat, [Display(....

For the time being, the Dto is mostly identical to the Entity and so I have been doing a copy/paste to keep the Dto in sync with things such as adding/removing fields.

For now it's pretty easy doing the copy/paste and things appear to be working with the annotations in both files. There are a lot of fields and I can see this becoming a maintenance nightmare.

Should annotations be specified in the Dto class like this, or does the Entity class handle this for my views? Maybe some annotations should be in the Entity and some in the Dto?

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are used as conditions for a object properties to be valid in certain conditions.

So assuming you post an object to a method.

It is not commonly used to post the entity itself but the Dto.

And the first condition it needs to pass is for example "ModelState.IsValid".

So if valid, continue executing the method or return a BadRequest.

In conlusion i think it is very important to use them in Dtos for example required,displayFormat etc. because you can check Dto validation before checking entity validation and if your code is good enough most of annotations can be exluded from the entity (I do not recommend it but you are saying that is confusing to you).

Meanwhile if you are doing any modification and not only mapping from Dto to entity you must use annotations to entity too.

I think you have to evaluate the anotation yourself.

I do have most of them only in Dto.

Hope i was clear and helped you.